# Save recursion values for further calculations

Tags: java

I have to find out the different combinations for an assignment (how to combine spices with different meals). I used a recursion to get the solution. The recursion is working and the J-Unit tests are successful. My problem is that I want to store my values which were calculated ones that the recursion does not calculate them again and again. 
Which opportunities do I have to do that?

This is my current code.

```
public class FoodCombinations {

  public static long tasty(int v, int g) {

    if (v == g || v == 1) {
        return 1 * 2;
    }
    return tasty(v - 1, g - 1) + v * tasty(v, g - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the values of each iteration and not the final result?

Comment: can you provide a usable code pls ? what is essen function ? what are v and g ?

Comment: Yes, values of each iteration. That the recursion "remember" the value and do not calculate it again.

Comment: pass an arraylist as parameter and save values in it. or have static arraylist defined and use it for storing value

Comment: Sorry should be return tasty(v-1,g-1) + v * tasty(v, g-1)

Comment: *and do not calculate it again* -- This is still not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The key word is memoization.

Store the results in a hashmap, look them up before the calculation. There is a slight complication about how to look up two arguments at once, to do this properly you would have to make a small class with two items that implements either the requirements for HashMap (hashCode) or for TreeMap (Comparable interface) and use that class as key. Or you could use a simple and dirty String hack:

```
public class FoodCombinations {

  static Map<String, Long> cache = new HashMap<>();

  public static long tasty(int v, int g) {
    String key = v+"|"+g;
    if (cache.containsKey(key)) return cache.get(key);
    long result;
    if (v == g || v == 1) {
        result = 1 * 2;
    } else {
        result = tasty(v - 1, g - 1) + v * tasty(v, g - 1);
    }
    cache.put(key, result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a private method. Looked at the end similar to your solution but with a private method instead of a hashmap.